# Calculating a residue?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

How would you calculate the residue of f(z) = $\frac{e^{az}}{sin(z)}$ ?

I got that the poles are when $sin(z) = 0$

Therefore z = $n\pi$ where n is an integer

And so the Residues are $e^{an\pi}$

The solution says something different

Comment: What does the answer say? What do you think went wrong? What is the context of the problem?

Comment: answer subs in pi - s for some reason and ends up getting -e^a(pi) as the residue. Im not really sure where i went wrong tbh :/. And that's the entire problem (it's just a small sub question)

Answer (score 0):

For $n\pi$ to be simple poles of $f$ they have to be simple roots of $1/f$,
namely of $\sin(z)=0$. Since $\sin(n\pi) = 0$ and $\frac{d}{dz} \sin(z)\Bigr|_{z=n\pi} = \cos(n\pi) \neq 0$ we conclude that $n\pi$ are simple poles of $f$.

Now you can compute the residue of $f$ at these points using the formula
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Res}(f,kn) &= 
\lim_{z\to n\pi} (z-n\pi)\frac{e^{az}}{\sin(z)} \\
&= \lim_{z\to n\pi} \frac{((z-n\pi){e^{az}})'}{(\sin(z))'}\\
&= \lim_{z\to n\pi}\frac{a(z-n\pi)e^{az}+e^{az}}{\cos(z)}\\
&= \frac{e^{a n\pi}}{\cos(n\pi)}\\
&=(-1)^n e^{a n\pi}
\end{align*}
where we used  L'Hospital's rule.